# Returning table name becomes string

Tags: postgresql

Hello I got 500 tables in public and I try to create triggers for all tables ,by first finding all table names and creating a trigger if not already exists here is the code:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_results() RETURNS VOID AS
  $BODY$
   DECLARE
 r RECORD;
BEGIN
 IF (SELECT "session_user"() <> 'asdf' THEN
 FOR r IN (SELECT 'CREATE TRIGGER ' || tab_name|| '_if_modified_trg AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON ' || tab_name|| ' FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.if_modified_func(); ' AS trigger_creation_query
 FROM (
 SELECT  quote_ident(table_name) as tab_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='public'
AND table_type != 'VIEW'


)  AS foo WHERE tab_name||'_if_modified_trg' NOT IN (SELECT tgname from pg_trigger where not tgisinternal))

 LOOP

-- can do some processing here
EXECUTE r.trigger_creation_query;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
END IF;
END
$BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
 SELECT * FROM get_all_results();
```

and I get this error :

```
   ERROR:  syntax error at or near "_if_modified_trg"
   LINE 1: CREATE TRIGGER "position"_if_modified_trg AFTER INSERT OR UP...
```

I really have table position in one of these 500 and the name is position not "position".

Comment: If you don't want quotes, then don't call `quote_ident()`